# Windows Explorer: file type is just a square character for some files

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Windows Explorer is showing a square for certain file types instead of a legible name:

[image]

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Regedit
2. Open "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dat" and look at the (default) to the right.  This will *probably* be ***datfile***. (Windows does this by default).
3. Open "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\***datfile***" (or whatever you read on step 2).
4. Look to the right at "(Default)".  That is where this text comes from.

My first thought it that this is a symptom of registry corruption.  You should probably run `chkdsk` on your drive.

Also, you are probably wondering why the square? .. it is because whatever is in that registry key is not a printable value using the windows font the explorer is showing you that window with.  That is why I think it *might* be corruption.

Comment: Thanks, I've deleted the key and stuff is back to normal (DAT File), that square ended up being a 0x08 character... No problem with chkdsk, ran it lately, rather, I think I've probably installed too many Windows 9X software and at some point, one of them was not so well-behaved .